# How/Where to find the theoretically expected cross-correlation between CMB and Large-Scale Structure in real sapce?

Tags: cosmology, experimental-physics, astrophysics, cosmic-microwave-background, observable-universe

I have cross correlated the CMB map (WMAP 7 Year map) and the large-scale structure tracer- quasar (NBC-KDE Quasar catalog from SDSS-6 [avilable here](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/W3Browse/galaxy-catalog/sdssnbckde.html#bii)) in real space by following the [this paper](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_url?url=https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.74.063520&hl=en&sa=T&oi=gsb&ct=res&cd=0&d=598451148523458528&ei=x-tRZMGpJ4r8mgGIlKNI&scisig=AGlGAw8L9Sc_gY-tKCUk24hkb_lK) by Tommaso Giannantonio. I have computed the observed CCF and I need to compare it to the Lambda CDM theoretical prediction CCF based on WMAP (whatever year) best-fit parameters as the paper does in figure-7. Please help in finding this theoretical expectation. Either guide me on how to generate it myself or guide me to a resource where its already available.

Thank you.